# C++ base and sub class circular references

Tags: c++, class, include

I have a C++ class game with sub class player which has subclasses building and citizen.

```
class Game 
{
class player 
{
class citizen{};
class building{};
};
};
```

each of those classes are in their own .cpp

I want to store my created players in an array in the game class but I end up needing to include my subclass in my baseclass which needs to include my parent class to be defined.

I still have a lot to learn from C++, but I feel the only way to get over that is to put the array in the player class as static. is there better ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you *really* need the classes to be nested? For example, you could define an *independent* `player` class and then have a member (object) of that class in your `Game` class, and so forth.

Comment: ... or even have a vector (or array) of `player` objects, if you need more than one player in the game (which seems likely).

Comment: i think i could take the player out of the game class, but i still have the same kind of problem with my subclasses wich i also intended to keep each member in an array in the parent class.  should i instead make my arrays static and put a owner variable?

Comment: You don't need to nest the classes.  However, if `Game` contains an instance of `Player`, then the compiler needs visibility of the definition of `Player` (e.g. from a header file) when compiling `Game`.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that you don't need the *definition* of your 'subclasses' in their container classes in order to use them from those classes. You can just define member object(s)/vector(s) of the required 'sub' classes in each containing class that needs them.

Comment: Static variables almost always indicates bad design (there are exceptions of course), but in this case you should not need to have a static array. I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, but i'd recommend thinking more about it.

Comment: I'd argue that player should not be a nested class. It should be in its own header file and included by your Game class (or forward declared if possible).

Comment: is there a way to achieve it with player being nested? since my building and citizen will be nested in player i will have the same problem. if i dont include the header of the subclass and just forward declare it i cannot create an array containing elements of.

there might be something fundementals missing in my understanding, i am fairly new to object oriented programming.

Comment: I think an important missing piece of information is _why_ do you want to nest these classes? Once we understand that, maybe then we can help you figure out how to accomplish what you are doing. Right now, this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Might be true, i think i just didn't realise my classes could not be nested but have each "base class" having an array of their own "subclass" member.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you've defined multiple classes within your class. In the spirit of good coding practices, each logical unit (i.e. your classes) should be defined separately, and then maybe included as members inside of other classes (but does **not** have its own definition within the class that contains it).

So, if a `Game` object has a list of `Player` objects, as well as `Citizen` and `Building` objects, then you want something that looks more like:

```
class Player {
    //Player definition
}

class Citizen {
    //Citizen definition
}

class Building {
    //Building definition
}

class Game {
    private:
        Player myPlayersList[4]; //an array of 4 player objects
        Citizen someCitizen; //a single Citizen object
        Building someBuilding; //a single Building object
    //more Game definition
}
```

Feel free to comment back if you have any questions!

Comment: i think you just made me realize how i can actually do this. i can have each class as it's own and then just put an array of these other classes in my class that needs it. That should resolve my problem. My thanks to you (and the other guys who commented on my question) if it works.